# Meteor: how to show the server url / ip

Tags: meteor, xcode6

I have built an iOS app with meteor.
I can run it using this command:
`meteor run ios-device --mobile-server=XXX.XX.XX.XXX`

It opens Xcode, where I can export my app as an `ipa` as a Ad Hoc deployment.
So far so good.

Now I install the app from my mac on iPad 1, where everything works as a charm.

The problem comes when I install the same app using a different PC (windows 10) on iPad 2.

When the app on iPad 2 starts, it doesnt seem to connect to my server. (at this moment, the computers are on Wifi 1, and both the iPads are connected to my phone hotspot).

So basically, it seems to me that I have one app, installed on two different iPads having two different behaviours.

I tried to display `Meteor.status().status` and on iPad 1 it says `connected` and iPad 2: `connecting` then `waiting` on a loop.

As I don't have a clue why it is happening, I am thinking for some reason iPad 2 is trying to connect to maybe `localhost` or something, which would be why it can't connect to it.

But I don't know where to find the server url or ip it is trying to connect to ?
PS: as it is supposed to connect to XXX.XX.XX.XXX, I went to iPad 2 web browser, typed this ip, and the app loads nicely in the web browser.

Any help would be really appreciated !!! Thanks

Edit:

I just tried to install the app from my mac on iPad 2 using Xcode, and it also failed. It is stuck on `connecting` then `waiting`, ....

Comment: In my case this happened when I forgot to set a proxy correctly. I looks a lot like a simple connection problem on the one ipad. You can find ipad apps to do 'ping' and 'curl', which might help identify the problem. I found a verbose 'curl' was often the most helpful.

Comment: thanks for the comment @mwarren - from safari I can access the web version of the app though (where the app is also supposed to connect to), so I am guessing that pinging xxx.xx.xx.xx would work

Comment: I you install from Windows 10 to Ipad1, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things to look out for...
- Make sure that the ipad has network connectivity

There is a bug report about something similar here
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/6130

This is closed, but you may be getting the same issue.

I have found that if I run 
meteor run ios-device --mobile-server xxx.xxx.xxx

prior to running a build (with --server xxx.xxx.xxx) then it works as expected - not sure why, but it seems to work

You can also set up the Safari inspector, look at the network activity and see what IP address it is connecting too - that will at least tell you why it is failing.

ROOT_URL also needs to be set correctly on  the server (although this is probably not your problem here), otherwise hot code push can mess up after the first one

Comment: Thanks for the help @Mikkel - about connectivity, I guess it is fine as I can access the web version of the app using safari. Safari inspector sounds like a great lead to find what IP it is trying to connect to ! I wont be able to test it before the weekend but will let you know !